# Previous link not displaying properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The link for previous is written as

```
<%= link_to '&#171; Previous', {:action => 'accounts'}, :class => 'blue float_left margin_top_8' %>
```

I want to display Previous link as `<< Previous` but I am getting `&#171; Previous` . How to fix it ?

Comment: You'd need something like `raw()` -> `<%= link_to raw('&#171; Previous'), {:action => 'accounts'}, :class => 'blue float_left margin_top_8' %>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to '&#171; Previous'.html_safe, {:action => 'accounts'}, :class => 'blue float_left margin_top_8' %>
```

Just add the `html_safe` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it in

```
"&#171; Previous".html_safe
```

or use

```
raw("&#171; Previous")
```

They're both indicating that the string you submit is "safe" to display